# was Ihnen dazu einfällt oder einfallen?

Tags: dative

> Schreiben Sie möglichst alles auf, was Ihnen dazu einfällt

Hallo, ich habe diesen Satz gelesen und verstehe nicht, warum man **einfällt** und nicht **einfallen** sagt.

Meine Vermutung ist, dass das der Originalsatz ist:

> Schreiben Sie möglichst alles auf, was es Ihnen dazu einfällt.

Dann ist es entfernt als Verkürzung.
Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 4):

Die Vermutung ist nicht richtig. Ein **es** ist hier nicht erforderlich.

Betrachten wir noch einmal den Satz:

> Schreiben Sie möglichst alles auf, was Ihnen dazu einfällt.

Das Relativpronomen *was* ist das Subjekt des Nebensatzes. Da es im Singular steht, muss *einfällt* ebenfalls im Singular stehen. Folglich wäre *einfallen* inkorrekt.

*Ihnen* ist das Dativobjekt des Nebensatzes. Da *einfallen* kein Akkusativobjekt verlangt, ist der Nebensatz damit vollständig und ein **es** ist wie oben bereits bemerkt weder erforderlich noch wäre es hier korrekt.

Comment: Vielen Dank :) 
Alles klar jetzt

Answer (score 2):

> ich ... verstehe nicht, warum man *einfällt* und nicht *einfallen* sagt

Im Deutschen werden die Verben flektiert, d.h. sie werden der Zahl (Numerus) und der Person nach an das Subjekt angepasst.

*Einfallen* ist die Grundform (Infinitiv), *einfällt* ist die 3. Person Singular. Da das Subjekt *was* im Singular ist und die Geschehnisse nicht aus dem Blickwinkel dieses Subjekts berichtet werden, ist die 3. Person Singular die korrekte Form.